# Python: creating wordclouds with timeslider, to see wordclouds change trough time

Tags: python, slider, word-cloud

I recently retrieved tweets over several years and months. I would now like to display by month and by year (so for example for 2 years: 24 wordclouds) the Tweet wordclouds with a corresponding timeslider. I already have the wordclouds (png or pdf) separately by looping through my months and years, but just can't get them presented with a timeslider. Someone who can help me?

I was thinking of using maybe "interact" and "IntSlider" of "ipywidgets"?

Thanks a lot!

I tried the for loop, and got 24 pdf's, and I tried "interact" but got no further than my sliders:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SyLfe.png)
Also interact in the for loop didn't work.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.